# Can't return self Objective-c Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, return, self

I just want to warn you that I'm french so sorry for my future mistakes.
I'm programming a snake game (you know, eat an apple and the snake gets longer) and I'm really stuck. I'm working with cocos2d and basically, the game is finish except that one thing. I just implement the collision management of the snake, with is own body. When it does, my function GameOver is called :

```
-(void)gameOver{
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [body count]; i++)
{
    [self removeChild:((SnakePart*)body[i]) cleanup:YES];
}

[self unscheduleUpdate];
[self removeChild:apple cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:scoreLabel cleanup:YES];

CCTransitionRotoZoom *transition = [CCTransitionSlideInB transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:   [EndGameLayer scene]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:transition];

}
```

I have put some breakpoints to see where the application is bugging, but it does not bug there. In fact, it seems to bug in the init of the EndGameLayer, which is call immediately afterwards. The init is :

```
-(id)init{

if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 255)]) ) {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Game Over.jpg"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);


    CCMenuItemFont *boutonRecommencer = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Restart" target:self selector:@selector(restart)];
    boutonRecommencer.fontSize = 28;
    boutonRecommencer.fontName = @"Helvetica";

    CCMenuItemFont *boutonMainMenu = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Main Menu" target:self selector:@selector(mainMenu)];
    boutonMainMenu.fontSize = 28;
    boutonMainMenu.fontName = @"Helvetica";

    CCMenu *menuEcranFin = [CCMenu menuWithItems:boutonRecommencer, boutonMainMenu, nil];
    [menuEcranFin setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2 ,winSize.height/2 - 65)];
    [menuEcranFin alignItemsInRows:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
    [menuEcranFin alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:40];

    [self addChild:background];
    [self addChild:menuEcranFin];
}
return self;
}
```

Then again, I put some breakpoints within this code, but the app goes through all of it without a problem, it seems that the problem is when it returns self but I really don't know. Also, this bug does not show up every time. Sometimes my gameOver screen is showed, and I can restart a game, and the try after, the bug comes back. Its almost always the first or second times when the gameOver shows up. Thanks a lot for your help.

*new* 
The bug shows up when I have a collision with myself and the error is a : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x800000008). I have already seen something like that when I reach an array out of bounds ... but in this case I really don't know. When I enable the Zombie objects, the error is : Thread 1 : EXC_Breakpoint (code=EXC=l386_BPT, subcode = 0x0).

Comment: Made sure you set the project into Debug mode when setting breakpoints -- otherwise if it's set to Release, the compiler optimization might skip many breakpoints

Comment: Your English is fine -- don't worry about that, but your description of your problem is a bit lacking. What _exactly_ is the nature of the bug? What happens, specifically? It would also help if you reduced the amount of code here -- us debugging by reading just some of your code is going to be a lot more work than you spending a little more time pinpointing the problematic lines.

Comment: Well I check breakpoints by breakpoints as xcode go, it doesn't skip any of them and there's not error until the end (return self of gameover). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks Josh for the advice, I put my code here in case someone already has this problem and if it has to do with not removing the scene of something I do not know about cocos2d.

Comment: Is it being properly retained? A crude way of seeing if it's being released too many times would be to call [self retain] before returning self. Or you could open up Instruments with NSZombies enabled and see when it gets retained/released that way. If that's the problem, you can pinpoint where the extra release is with Instruments

Comment: Well, I'll be honest with you Echihl, I followed a course and the teacher said to us that the memory management was handling all by itself, so no need to learn retain or anything that has to do with the memory. I'll search how to use your informations though , thanks.

Comment: I've found the NSZombie enable, and the error changed, its now : Thread 1 : EXC_Breakpoint (code=EXC=l386_BPT, subcode = 0x0).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem even if I don't understand. The line that cause the error was :

```
[self removeChild:apple cleanup:YES];
```

It seems like even if the game was getting through a function that use the apple even if after the GameOver function, the game end. It's kind of weird but anyway, now it works !